# Accessing attributes via Rails relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Position model for which I have a scope defined:

```
scope :default, where('is_default = ?', 1)
```

Idea being that I want to know which is the default position. I can do something like: @profile.positions.default and this returns an activerecord relation and the default position record. The issue is that now that I have the default record, I need to access other attributes of Positions such as title..

```
@profile.positions.default.title
```

but the above returns an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `title' for #

Any clues? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scope turns a `collection` of objects, not a single object, so you're trying to call `title` on an array of ActiveRecord results.

You probably want something like this:

```
@profile.positions.default.first.title
```

Or if you always want just one record, you may switch from a scope to a class method:

```
def self.default
  where('is_default = ?', 1).first
end
```

Comment: Thanks, makes complete sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :positions
  has_one :default_position, :class_name => 'Position', 
                             :conditions => ['is_default = ?', true]
end
```

Then

```
@profile.default_position.title
```